# Python: Calling variables in one function from a seperate function but not using global variables

Tags: python, global-variables

I wrote the below code in order to check for three files and whichever files exist, run a "scan" on the file (if a file does not exist, don't worry about it just run a "scan" on the available files) and produce the proper output file on those available files.

The program I'm working on includes the following code:

```
def InputScanAnswer():
    scan_number = raw_input("Enter Scan Type number: ")
    return scan_number
```

This function checks if these three files exist and if so, assign specific values to `hashcolumn` and to `filepathNum`

```
def chkifexists():
    list = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv']
    for filename in list:
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            if filename == "file1.csv":
                hashcolumn = 7
                filepathNum = 5
            if filename == "file2.csv":
                hashcolumn = 15
                filepathNum = 5
            if filename == "file3.csv":
                hashcolumn = 1
                filepathNum = 0
            #print filename, hashcolumn, filepathNum


def ScanChoice(scan_number):
    if scan_number == "1":
        chkifexists()
        onlinescan(filename, filename + "_Online_Scan_Results.csv", hashcolumn, filepathNum) #this is what is giving me errors...
    elif scan_number == "2":
        print "this is scan #2"
    elif scan_number =="3":
        print "this is scan #3"
    else:
        print "Oops! Invalid selection. Please try again."


def onlinescan(FileToScan, ResultsFile, hashcolumn, filepathNum):
    # web scraping stuff is done in this function
```

The error that I run into is `global name 'filename' is not defined`.
I realize that the problem is I'm attempting to send local variables from `chkifexists()` to the `onlinescan()` parameters. I tried using

```
return filename
return hashcolumn
return filepathNum
```

at the end of the `chkifexists()` function but that was not working either. Is there anyway to do what I'm trying to do in the

```
onlinescan(filename, filename + "_Online_Scan_Results.csv", hashcolumn, filepathNum)
```

line **without** using global variables? I know they are discouraged and I'm hoping I can go about it another way. Also, does having `hashcolumn` and `filepathNum` parameters in `onlinescan()` have anything to do with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside `chkifexists`, you would return all three variables like so:

```
return (filename, hashcolumn, filepathNum)
```

You would retrieve these by calling the function like so:

```
(filename, hashcolumn, filepathNum) = chkifexists()
```

You now have them in your function scope without needing global variables!

Technically, you don't need the parenthesis, either.  In fact, I'm not sure why I included them.  But it works either way, so what the heck.

Comment: What about the order? Can it also be like this: `chkifexists() = filename, hashcolumn, filepathNum` ?

Comment: That's easy enough to try in your interpreter, but since I'm feeling generous, I'll give you the answer: no, you get a `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`.  Which, when you think about it for a secoond, makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Good answer. I think the parenthesis convey that you're not returning three things, you're returning one thing -- a `tuple` -- which you pack three variables into on the fly and unpack again on the fly on the other side.

Comment: @agf - that is true.  Leaving off the parenthesis *is* sort of just sugar; you're passing a tuple either way.